# How to add text to file at fixed position php?

Tags: php, file, fopen

I have this code:

```
$new_news = '; array(
    \'img\' =>'.$path.',
    \'title\' => '.$_POST["title"].',
    \'text\' => '.$_POST["text"].'
)';
```

and I need to add this to existing array in db.php. for example:

```
$news = array(
    array(
    'img' => 'images/egle.jpg', 
    'title' => 'Egle pārtraukusi ',
    'text' => 'Valsts prezidenta Andra '));
```

How can I add $new_news in length-4 using fopen()?

Comment: Do you mean you just want to add the array `$new_news` to `$news`? Also, what do you mean with length-4?

Comment: use array_merge, $news[] with $new_news

Comment: i don't get it, are you actually trying to store data in an array in .php file??

Answer (score 2):

Change `$new_news` to an array, not string.

```
$new_news = array(
  'img'   => $path, 
  'title' => $_POST["title"],
  'text'  => $_POST["text"]
);

$news[] = $new_news;
```